# Angular 9, aot, build optimizer, localize

Tags: angular, localization, translation, angular9

I am running an angluar 9 cli command to build an app like this:

```
ng build --configuration=production --aot=true --build-optimizer --localize --source-map=false
```

But I receive error:

```
Localized bundle generation failed: Unexpected messageParts for `$localize` (expected an array of strings).
```

If I run only `ng build --localize` it works fine, so I assume it is something due to optimizer and aot?

Comment: did u install @angular/localize ?

Comment: also u can fix actions for production configuration in angular.json and dont use so many flags

Comment: Yes, as I said, I've installed localize, and it works if I run ng build --localize, yes, I have set them in configuration

Comment: this is a bug request i think

Comment: I removed optimizer and it generates localized bundle. I will ask on Angular github and post the url here.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35376